# Search and extract substring from single cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following situation in Excel. `Column A` contains a list of benchmarks (e.g. *S&P TSX 60*), while `B1` contains a list of composite benchmarks with percentages in front of each benchmark:

```
5% S&P 500/
25% S&P 500 Financial/
50% S&P TSX 60 (ex-Energy)/
20% CAC 40
```

I need to be able to extract the percentage if the composites contain the benchmark. I was able to do most of it, but can't seem to figure out the data validation step.

As you can see in the figure, *S&P TSX 60* is not in the composite, but *S&P TSX 60 (ex-Energy)* is. Yet the formula still returns the percentage for both *S&P TSX 60* and *S&P TSX 60 (ex-Energy)*.

What additional thing is needed in the Excel formula to prevent this?

Or will it be easier to do in VBA?

[image]

Comment: Is it possible for you to unmerge those two cells? It would be a lot easier to do if you could split that into a four row group somewhere...

Comment: The percentage benchmarks are separated by `/` so you could add a `/` to `A2&"/"` and also add a slash to `B$1&"/"` because the the last entry doesn't have one.  This means that  `S&P TSX 60/` will not be found in `S&P TSX 60 (ex-Energy)/`

Comment: I tested Gordon's answer and it's exactly what I needed. Many thanks to Gordon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula should work for you:

```
=IFERROR(MID($B$1,FIND(A2&"/",$B$1&"/")-4,3),"")
```

[image]

But you should give @Gordon credit for his great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula `=IFERROR(LEFT(MID($B$1,SEARCH(A2&"/",$B$1,1)-4,LEN(A2)),3),"-")`

[image]